# Are there still Earth monarchies in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek

Within the *Star Trek* universe, are there still active monarchies on Earth, as there are today? Or have these been eradicated/removed as humanity evolved?  If they have been removed, how was this done?

If not, what is their function in the 23rd Century and beyond?

Comment: *"Dialogue from "Our Man Bashir" and "The Trouble with Tribbles" implies that Britain no longer exists as a sovereign country in the 23rd and 24th century. It may have lost its sovereignty by joining the European Alliance or United Earth. However, this may depend upon the internal political functioning of both the United Earth and the European Alliance."* - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Old_Britain

Comment: Earth had a [Borg Queen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_Queen) at several points.

Comment: @Valorum   You might want to look at this article  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-sovereign_monarchy#:~:text=A%20non%2Dsovereign%20monarchy%2C%20subnational,authority%20higher%20than%20their%20own.  and this list:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_non-sovereign_monarchs  There are more non sovereign  monarchs today than there are monarchs of sovereign countries.  So whether or not Britain is sovereign does not determine whether  Britain could retain a monarcy.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - OP asked about "active monarchies". I took that to mean *those with political power of some description*.